# Error: unsupported network (argument="network", value={"name":"sepolia","chainId":11155111}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.7.2)

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, ethers.js, alchemy

I am trying to interact with my smart contract for my nextjs app. I cannot interact with the contract because my alchemy provider is not working.

Attempt 1:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider(
    "sepolia",
    process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY
);
```

Error: unsupported network (argument="network", value={"name":"sepolia","chainId":11155111}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=providers/5.7.2)
Attempt 2:

```
const alchemyProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.ALCHEMY_URL);
export const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    contractABI,
    provider
);
```

Error: could not detect network (event="noNetwork", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.7.2)

---

Attempt 1 immediately breaks.
Attempt 2 breaks when I try to run a function from the contract. I can console.log() the contract and it is correct. No matter what I put as the parameter it will still initialize the contract.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using nextjs, but I got it working on my React app like this:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

const provider = new ethers.AlchemyProvider("sepolia", process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY)
```

Comment: BTW, this is ethers v6 api.

Answer (score 0):

It is not happening with sepolia mate, try goerli. worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need `ethers` **v6** to support `sepolia` testnet.

e.g. in `package.json`:

```
"ethers": "^6.8.1",
```

And the api changed bit, you call `ethers.AlchemyProvider()` to get the alchemy provider, e.g:

```
const alchemyProvider = new ethers.AlchemyProvider(network = "sepolia", "your_api_key");
```

Doc: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/providers/

Answer (score -1):

The Sepolia network, which is a testnet for the Ethereum 2.0 beacon chain. However, as of now the `AlchemyProvider` does not support this network, as it only supports the mainnet and some common testnets such as Rinkeby, Ropsten, Kovan and Goerli.

https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/ethers-js-provider